# How to find all the linear transformations from $X$ to $X$?

Tags: linear-transformations, finite-fields

I am considering the space of $mod~2$ space, e.g., 1+1=0.

If $X=\left\{ (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1) \right\}$, how can I find all the linear transformations from $X$ to $X$?

Do I have to check all $4^4=256$ functions, one by one?

Comment: This is still a vector space (of dimension 2) so it suffices to examine a basis.

Comment: There are only 16 matrices.

Comment: @Gribouillis Why are there 16 matrices? every element can go to the one among fours, can't it?

Comment: if $f:(0,0) \to (0,0)$, $(1,0) \to (1,0)$, $(0,1) \to (0,1)$, and $(1,1) \to (1,1)$, then for any $u$ or $v$, $f(u+v) = f(u)+f(v)$ and $f(cu)=cf(u)$ holds. Thus, $f$ is a linear transformation. Do I have to check all pairs?

Comment: From linear algebra you should recall either that A) a linear transformation is determined uniquely by where it maps the elements of a basis, and the images of the basis elements can be chosen freely, or B) if we fix a basis of an $n$-dimensional space $X$, then a linear transformation is uniquely determined by its matrix, and every matrix gives a linear transformation (w.r.t. that basis). Checking linearity conditions for each $u,v,c$ is a waste of time.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am sorry for my ignorance of linear albegra, can you give me some examples?